# Flutter how to create a loop in else if

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement

i got a chart that display months (in french) when i go below the month == 1, i would like to go back to my current month and not see my 'error'.
Is there a method to make it ?

```
String numericToStringMonth(int month) {
  if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
    return 'error';
  } else if (month == 1) {
    return 'Janvier';
  } else if (month == 2) {
    return 'Février';
  } else if (month == 3) {
    return 'Mars';
  } else if (month == 4) {
    return 'Avril';
  } else if (month == 5) {
    return 'Mai';
  } else if (month == 6) {
    return 'Juin';
  } else if (month == 7) {
    return 'Juillet';
  } else if (month == 8) {
    return 'Août';
  } else if (month == 9) {
    return 'Septembre';
  } else if (month == 10) {
    return 'Octobre';
  } else if (month == 11) {
    return 'Novembre';
  } else if (month == 12) {
    return 'Décembre';
  } else {
    return 'error';
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem here, can you explain more what you want to do?

Comment: and you can remove the first if statement since the last else statement will handle other invalid inputs

Comment: Why should an invalid input result in a valid output?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
String numericToStringMonth(int month) {
  // make list of months for easier access
  List<String> months = [
    'Janvier',
    'Février',
    'Mars',
    'Avril',
    'Mai',
    'Juin',
    'Juillet',
    'Août',
    'Septembre',
    'Octobre',
    'Novembre',
    'Décembre'
  ];

  int currentMonth = month - 1;

  try {
    if (currentMonth > 11) {
      throw Exception('Month must be between 1 and 12');
    } else if (currentMonth < 0) {
// setting month to the first one when value goes below 0, add your logic here
      currentMonth = 1;
    }
    return months[currentMonth];
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  return '';
}
```